# How to add attribute when onclick event in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Hi how can i add attribute into a button when button is clicked?

this is the attribute `dojotype="dijit.form.Button"`

```
void ButtonLogin_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 // the add attribute
}
```

this is my button

```
<button id="ButtonLogin" runat="server" onServerClick="ButtonLogin_OnClick"   jsid="ButtonLogin" style="float: right;
                            padding: 5px 15px 0px 0px;">
                           Login</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

inside `ButtonLogin_OnClick` do

```
this.ButtonLogin.Attributes.Add("dojotype", "dijit.form.Button");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by JQUERY. I'm adding attribute to "a" tag:

```
     <a href="#" id="btnAttrib">Add Attrib</a>
     <script type="text/javascript">
            $("#btnAttrib").click(function () {
                $("#btnAttrib").attr("rel", "nofollow");                  
             })
     </script>
```

I think you change it to:

```
     <button id="ButtonLogin" runat="server" onServerClick="ButtonLogin_OnClick" jsid="ButtonLogin" style="float: right;padding: 5px 15px 0px 0px;">Login</button>

     <script type="text/javascript">
            $("#ButtonLogin").click(function () {
                $("#ButtonLogin").attr("dojotype", "dijit.form.Button");                  
             })
     </script>
```